# In React Router 6, update router data after the route is rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, breadcrumbs

In my application, I have a Breadcrumb component that uses the Router nested path to show the crumbs.

```js
const matches = useMatches();

function createBreadcrumbList() {
  const breadcrumb = [];
  matches.forEach((route, index) => {
    const crumb = {};
    crumb.label = BREADCRUMB_PAGE_MAP[route.id];
    if (!crumb.label) return;

    if (matches.length - index > 1) crumb.to = route.pathname;
    breadcrumb.push(crumb);
  });

  return breadcrumb;
}
```

This creates a breadcrumb of this format,

> Home > Users > User Info

The current setup works well for static values in the breadcrumb (Home, Users, etc). But I need a dynamic value present for the last route. For the User Info route I want to show the name of the user and a count.

> Home > Users > Dennis (10)

[image: screenshot]

This data however is loaded dynamically after the route loads.

Is it possible to trigger an action that sets this data on the route and will cause the matches hook to run again?

Here is the Codesandbox link for this,
https://codesandbox.io/s/router-breadcrumb-h6trtk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to retain my current code while implementing this requirement. I wanted a complete separation between the application code and breadcrumb functionality.

The best way I found to update the data in the route, was to navigate to the same route once the data was ready and pass the data as a state object.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (posts.length > 0) {
    const postsStr = posts.length > 0 ? ` (${posts.length})` : "";
    navigate(location.pathname, {
      replace: true,
      state: { breadcrumb: { pageName: `${selectedUser?.name}${postsStr}` } }
    });
  }
}, [posts]);
```

In the breadcrumb I used this location object and used the saved value for the current route.

```js
export default function useBreadcrumb() {
  const matches = useMatches();
  const location = useLocation();
  ...
  ...

  let label = BREADCRUMB_PAGE_MAP[route.id];
  if (route.pathname === location.pathname) {
    label = location?.state?.breadcrumb?.pageName || label;
  }
  crumb.label = label;

  ...
  ...
```

Here is the link to the fixed codesandbox,

https://codesandbox.io/s/router-breadcrumb-fix-d4qv2w

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using a Data Router then this is likely a good use case for using route [handles](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#handle). Add a `handle` prop to these routes that returns  an object with the breadcrumb data you want to render.

AppRouter

```
function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Route
      id="home"
      element={<IndexPage />}
      handle={{
        crumb: () => <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      }}
    >
      <Route index element={<App />} />
      <Route
        id="user"
        path="users"
        handle={{
          crumb: () => <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        }}
      >
        <Route id="viewAll" index element={<Users />} />
        <Route
          id="userInfo"
          path=":userId"
          element={<UserInfo />}
          handle={{
            crumb: (data) => <Link to={data?.link}>{data?.user}</Link>
          }}
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  );
}
```

Update the `Breadcrumb` component to use the `useMatches` hook to read the handle data and pass the appropriate data if the `crumb` is a callback function.

Breadcrumb

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useMatches, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Breadcrumb() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  const { userData: users } = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const { userId } = useParams();
  const selectedUser = users.find((user) => String(user.id) === userId);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const postsResponse = await fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`
      );
      const postData = await postsResponse.json();
      setPosts(postData);
    })();
  }, [userId]);

  const matches = useMatches();
  const crumbs = matches
    // first get rid of any matches that don't have handle and crumb
    .filter((match) => Boolean(match.handle?.crumb))
    // now map them into an array of elements, passing data to each one
    .map((match) =>
      match.handle.crumb({
        user: [selectedUser?.name, posts.length && `(${posts.length})`]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" "),
        link: `/users/${selectedUser?.id}`
      })
    );

  return (
    <div className="app-breadcrumb">
      {crumbs.map((crumb, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index}>
          {crumb}
          {crumbs.length - index > 1 && <p>&gt;</p>}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit in-react-router-6-update-router-data-after-the-route-is-rendered]

Obviously the code here is not optimized at all and duplicates the posts fetching for specific users. The posts could/should probably also be stored in your app's Redux store so it's only fetched once when & where needed, and the `UserInfo` route could use a loader function to read the state and return *exactly* what the breadcrumb needs for that route instead of doing it in the `BreadCrumb` component. The above should be a good place to start from though.